# CKEditor и KCFinder не работают

Tags: php

Проблема с загрузкой картинок на сервер с использованием редактора CKEditor и файлового менеджера KCFinder. На локальном сервере все работает прекрасно, а после загрузки на хостинг нет. При нажатии на кнопку «Выбор на сервере» открывается пустое окно.

В файле config.php параметр 'disabled'выставлен в false, права на папки выставлены в 777. Перепробовал кучу способов, не получилось. Загружать на сервер тоже не получается

Может кто-нить помочь?

Comment: Я думаю, что у вас проблема с путём к папке. Попробуйте добавить `__DIR__` к файлу пути, куда загружать и откуда брать файлы.

Comment: Да нет, с путями все нормально. Если неправильно написать, выдает ошибку, что путь не найден

Comment: Пути прописаны в js-конфиге, такого типа: config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';

Comment: Не путь к файлу скрипта, а путь, куда сохранять ваши файлы. Обычно он описан внутри `.php` файла.